# Angulajs - how to extract certain data from json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this json example where I need to get data individually.

json:

```
[
    {
        "web": "63",
        "mobile": "2525",

    },
    {
        "web": "70",
        "mobile": "1886",

    },
    {
        "web": "65",
        "mobile": "1044",

    }
]
```

then in the controller:

```
myData.get ().then (function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;//this is fine
            console.log(data);
            $scope.web = data.web//this does not work
            $scope.mobile = data.mobile//this does not work
            console.log($scope.data.web);//this does not work
            console.log($scope.web);//this does not work

            //and then lets say I want to pass them in the url
            var myUrl = "www.myurl.com/"+$scope.web+$scope.mobile;
      });
```

so basically I need to be able to work with individual data within the json file, so I can pass them them anywhere within the applications logic. What am I doing wrong?

heres plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Dre5j8yLDoJek89KCmak?p=preview

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `data` object inside `$scope`. So, if you try the following, it should work properly. `console.log($scope.data)` or `console.log($scope.data.web)`

In your controller, define an empty array and then assign the response to it.

```
var localdata = [];
// http call goes here
localdata = response.data;
// access the required members of localdata array
// since it's an array, you need to access individual data elements with index
// for example:
console.log($scope.data[0].web)
```

Comment: Define an empty array and then assign the response to it. Edited my answer.

Comment: not working, response is not defined even if I don't use response I need to access web or mobile

Comment: Modified the answer. I understood your issue now :)

Comment: cool, but how do you create a scope variable for web? so that you print all of them?

Comment: Didn't get you, can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. All I need to create is a variable/array or scope for web or mobile so that when you console out that variable(array) you get ALL the web or mobile values not just one. Sorry for being pain :(

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$scope.data = angular.fromJson(data);
console.log($scope.data);
```

and check

Comment: I get [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: try to make a $.each loop to data and then check

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. All I need to create is a variable/array or scope for web or mobile so that when you console out that variable(array) you get ALL the web or mobile values not just one. Sorry for being pain :(